# How to place TOC anywhere in word rendered Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a `Rmarkdown` which renders word document and it uses style from a [reference docx](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9lezxoxrauz4ls9wsia8h/template1.docx?rlkey=ddf6gbmh7qgsa4o57lzjiu7bn&dl=0)

Nothings included in the reference docx except for the style.

`Rmarkdown` Code:

````
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template1.docx
params:
  img_path1: your_file.png
---

```{r,include = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(officer)

```

```
::: {custom-style="Title"}
![](Images/your_image.png)\
I'm a title centered
:::

::: {custom-style="Title_2"}
I'm also a title centered\
For `r Sys.Date()`\
\
:::

\newpage

::: {custom-style="heading_2"}
Copyright
:::

::: {custom-style="paragraph1"}
This is a paragraph, so that's great
:::

::: {custom-style="heading_2"}
Lore Ipsum what is this
:::

\newpage

<!-- I want to create TOC right here which includes both heading and subheading with page number-->

<!-- Heading 1 styles are from reference docx-->
::: {custom-style="Heading 1"}
1 Objective
:::

::: {custom-style="paragraph1"}
lorem ipsum of this is just
:::

::: {custom-style="Heading 1"}
2 Summary
:::

::: {custom-style="Heading 2"}
2.1 Superb and Usage Summary
:::
````

**Question**:
I want to include TOC starting from the second page which would include the page number as well. Moreover I have also looked at a workaround from [Garrick Aden Bui](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/add-a-generated-table-of-contents-anywhere-in-rmarkdown/) but it only gives table of contents in bullet points which is not what I wanted.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `block_toc()` function from `officer` can help you generate table of content anywhere in your word document.

```
officer::block_toc()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `title`, `subtitle`, and `date` in the YAML header. In your reference file, activate the "Page Break Before" option for "TOC Heading" paragraph style.

````
---
title: I'm a title centered
subtitle: I'm also a title centered
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: true
    reference: template1.docx
---

<!-- Heading 1 styles are from reference docx-->
::: {custom-style="Heading 1"}
1 Objective
:::

::: {custom-style="paragraph1"}
lorem ipsum of this is just
:::

::: {custom-style="Heading 1"}
2 Summary
:::

::: {custom-style="Heading 2"}
2.1 Superb and Usage Summary
:::
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is a good workaround but my title page also includes images and table in the first page which is not included in this question code.

Comment: I see. Please include that piece of information in your question.

Comment: I have edited the Rmarkdown code.